# Can I set a video length limit on a HTML5 file upload?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, html

When uploading a video through a HTML5 input such as:

`<input type="file" id="input">`

I know it is possible to set a limit on the file size using PHP / Node.Js.

Is there a way to set a limit on the video length, not the file size?

I.E: Only allow a user to upload videos which are 15 seconds or less.

Comment: Try this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623222/set-duration-of-video-playback-with-html5 It may solve your needs.

Comment: You will always need to accept the file on the server to run a mediaInfo query to see what length the clip is, from there if it is too long you can delete it. But it will need to reach your server to be sure. . -> **The reason is you cannot perform any actions on the clients filesystem, which you would need to.**

Comment: Hmm. That could do the trick if the client is okay with uploading the whole file first. I don't think there could possibly be any way to tell this information before uploading the file like you can with file size, but if anyone else has an idea it would really save me! Thanks JD.

Comment: @user1929274 I may have spoken too soon : https://mediainfo.js.org/ -> **I have not tried this personally nor am I aware of it's inner functions** This might work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found:

**Solution 1:**
Create a video element that plays a local video file and then runs video.duration on it.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function myFunction() { 
    alert(vid.duration);
} 

(function localFileVideoPlayer() {
 'use strict'
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
  var displayMessage = function (message, isError) {
    var element = document.querySelector('#message')
    element.innerHTML = message
    element.className = isError ? 'error' : 'info'
  }
  var playSelectedFile = function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0]
    var type = file.type
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video')
    var canPlay = videoNode.canPlayType(type)
    if (canPlay === '') canPlay = 'no'
    var message = 'Can play type "' + type + '": ' + canPlay
    var isError = canPlay === 'no'
    displayMessage(message, isError)

    if (isError) {
      return
    }

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    videoNode.src = fileURL
  }
  var inputNode = document.querySelector('input')
  inputNode.addEventListener('change', playSelectedFile, false)
})()
```

```html
<h3>Step 1: Upload a video</h3>
<h3>Step 2: Get length</h3>
<h3>Step 3: ???</h3>
<h3>Step 4: Profit</h3>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Get video length</button>
<hr>
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<video controls autoplay id="myVideo"></video>
```

**Solution 2:** use mediainfo.js https://mediainfo.js.org/