# How to access the attribute "t" of "src="video/journey27.mp4#t=16,20" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This code loads video and starts it at second 16 and finishes it at second 20.

```js
function playVideo(str) { 
  document.getElementById("myVideo").src = str;
  document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime=16;
    
  document.getElementById("myVideo").(what should I put here????????)=20;
    
  document.getElementById("myVideo").start();
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="1000" height="800" controls autoplay loop>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
    
<a onclick="playVideo('video/journey27.mp4')">Play</a>
```

I tried `document.getElementById("myVideo").endTime=20` but it didn't work.

How to access the attribute "`t`" of  `src="video/journey27.mp4#t=16,20` in javascript?

Comment: @Phil, No, I want to call the attribute "t" in "<iframe src="video/journey27.mp4#t=16,20"></iframe>"; we have "document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime=16", do we have   "document.getElementById("myVideo").endTime=20"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Duration of video playback with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31623222/283366)

Comment: Does this code that you provided is inside the iframe? Or is iframe somewhere, but you didn't include it?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I don't want the "#t=16,20". I want code that can help me to manipulate the video

Comment: It doesn't answer my question at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this? It will get your string and concatenate it with your `t` paramter.

```js
function playVideo(str) { 
  const src = str + "#t=16,20";
  document.getElementById("myVideo").src = src;
  document.getElementById("myVideo").start();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const truncateString = (string = '', maxLength = 50) => string.length > maxLength ? `${string.substring(27, maxLength)}`:string //here 27 is total number of characters in a string
    let text = "video/journey27.mp4#t=16,20";
    let result = truncateString(text,20); //here 20 is that how many characters you want to cut down from your string

    console.log(result)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to get a string. I want to call the attribute "t" in "<iframe src="video/journey27.mp4#t=16,20"></iframe>"; we have "document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime=16", do we have "document.getElementById("myVideo").endTime=20"?